# Trouble with react private routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context

I'm trying to create protected routes. I have a react context that returns `true or false` if the user is signed in or not.

The problem is that even if I'm authenticated I still can't visit the dashboard route (it redirects to login even if im signed in). I think this is because I send an api request to my server to check if the user is authenticated and in that time context value is `undefined`

I've tried to solve this to create by checking if the context was undefined before rendering the route but it still doesn't work.

App.js

```
const ctx = useContext(userContext);
  console.log(ctx.authed); // return true or false

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/auth/register' component={Register}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/auth/login' component={Login}></Route>

          {!ctx.loading ? (
            <ProtectedRoute
              path='/dashboard'
              isAuth={ctx.authed}
              exact
              component={Dashboard}
            />
          ) : null}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
```

ProtectedRoute.js

```
function ProtectedRoute({ isAuth, component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (isAuth) {
          return <Component />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', 
            state: { from: props.location } }} />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

and my context looks like:

```
export const userContext = createContext({});
export default function Context(props) {
  const [authed, setAuthed] = useState(undefined);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: 'include',
      url: '/checkAuthentication',
    }).then((res) => {
      setAuthed(res.data.authenticated);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <userContext.Provider value={{ loading, authed }}>
      {props.children}
    </userContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: what do you see when you console.log `isAuth` in your protected route?

Comment: `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);` loading starts as false, is set to `true` on future render after `useEffect` is triggered, this probably means that it still initially renders the ProtectedRoute and does the redirect before loading the user. If you intend to load straight away using a `useEffect` why not initialise loading as true?

Comment: @azium isAuth at first logs `undefined` but when the api returns it changes to `true`

Comment: is your `render` block not getting called again when it changes to `true`?

Comment: how are you navigating to the dashboard? do you have a `Link` component somewhere or do you call `navigate` or `history.push` in your login component?

Comment: @azium I'm using this project to test things out so as of now I just type `/dashboard`

Comment: @azium I'm not sure if this helps but if I harcode  isAuth to true or false it works as intended.

Comment: if you're just typing it in `/dashboard` then it will always kick you right away because that triggers all your auth logic to rerun

Comment: @azium even if I use a link it does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alyks solution helped me. Nothing was changed except the addition of the useEffect block.

```
  const ctx = useContext(myContext);
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(ctx.authed);

  useEffect(() => {             //
    if (ctx.authed) {           //
      setIsAuth(ctx.authed);   <-- added this
    }                           //
  }, [ctx.authed]);             // 

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Router>
        <a href='/dashboard'>Dashboard</a>
        <a href='/auth/login'>Login</a>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/auth/register' component={Register}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/auth/login' component={Login}></Route>

          {!ctx.loading ? (
            <ProtectedRoute
              path='/dashboard'
              isAuth={isAuth}
              exact
              component={Dashboard}
            />
          ) : null}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` hook to find out when react changed your `authed` variable. When it happens you can check if the user is logged in. If not, you can use `history.push('/login')`. You can get `history` from `useHistory` hook of `react-router-dom`. In your login page you can use context's loading variable to show any loading component.

With this method you don't need to use redundant component which is hard to manage and decreases the readability of the code.

The problem of your code is that when component is mounted, context's `loading` variable is always false and `authed` value at this moment is `undefined`. That's why `<ProtectedRoute />` is always rendering and redirecting you to login page.

Comment: This helped. Basically I set a useEffect to check if `ctx.authed` was undefined, if it wasnt I passed it onto the protected route. I added a code block to the bottom of my question showing what I did, thank you!

Comment: @user Instead of adding the answer to your question, post it below as an actual answer.